# IIFE and Global scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, iife

Why does the following code result in logging of `b` while `a` is still `undefined`?

```
(function(){ var a=b=5; })();
console.log('b:'+b);
console.log('a:'+a);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `var a=b=5;` statement defines only local `a` variable and in fact is interpreted like

```
var a = (b=5);
```

which equals to

```
b = 5;
var a = 5;
```

which assigns `5` to a global `b` variable and defines a local `a` variable.

The proper way to define 2 local variables without value repetition would be

```
var b = 5, a = b;
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript if you ommit the var keyword before a variable, it will be considered as global.
So here **b** is a global variable and **a** is only a local to that function's scope.
That's why you are getting the error while accessing the **a**.

Answer (score 0):

A variable can be defined in 2 ways:

- var a= 5 // first
- a=5      // Second

In first way, `a` is a local variable, but in second way, it becomes a global variable.

So, when you do `var a=b=5`, `b` is a global variable and hence retains value.

Comment: What is "fist method" and "second method" you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out myself as it wouldn't let me sleep.

There are 2 assignments happening within the IIFE whereas only 1 declaration.

The statement `var a=b=5;` declares the variable `a` with `var` but simply does assignment for the other variable `b`.
`b` is actually never declared here, just assigned - making it a *global variable*.

Hence `b` is accessible to the log statement *outside* the function, which prints its value as `5`.

In other words, under 'strict' mode, the code will look like this:

```
(function() {
   'use strict';
   var a = window.b = 5;
})();

console.log(b);
```